# The ip addresses of all eBGP routers on the Internet

Tags: ip-address, ping, latency, measurement, bgp

I need to measure the latency from a specific location of the Internet to all of the other ISPs on the Internet. My plan is to measure the ping delay from a server to all of eBGP routers on the Internet. The problem I do not know what is the Ip address of eBGP routers to prob them. I searched a lot and I can not find any data set which has those IP addresses. I checked CAIDA dataset too and we have just the AS numbers and their prefixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no an easy way of doing this. You can find edge BGP routers by doing traceroutes and capturing the IP when the AS changes in the path. Saying that, most of the BGP routers filter out ICMP traffic and might reply back with a different IP address than the one it uses for BGP sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I would be very surprised if these were publicly published anywhere. The general public has no need of knowing these; the only parties that have a valid reason for knowing the public IP address of an ISPs eBGP router is another ISP or customer that has a BGP session to the eBGP router. Publishing those IP addresses would only invite attackers. Even if you knew the IP addresses, it is quite possible that the ISP would filter ICMP traffic (i.e. not respond to pings).

UPDATE: I thought of a way in which you can gather some (maybe even many, but definitely not all) of the eBGP peering addresses. Log into as many BGP looking glasses as you can, and observe the BGP next-hops of the BGP routes in the RIB. This will give you the peering addresses of the eBGP neighbors of the router on which that particular looking glass is running. Maybe a service like ThousandEyes can provide similar insights (not sure - I am not a user of ThousandEyes and I am not sure what information they do or don't provide).